# Set TextView's portion of text color?

Tags: android, textview

I want to set color to portion of text using `Html.fromHtml()` method.

My code is

```
String name =  "<font color=\"#B034A2\">" + notificationListBean.getUsername() + "</font>"
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(name));
```

But textcolor is not changed.

I also tried this but this also not working

```
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(name);        
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.noti_color)), 0, name.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

`textview.setText(wordtoSpan);`

What changes should i do?

Comment: are you sure that `textview` is displayed at screen?

Comment: yes but color not changed

Comment: post the place where you are retrieving the TextView.

Comment: I use this textview in adapter class in getView method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday i have faced same problem with `Html.fromHtml()` so i have used spannable string here is how i will edit your code

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

                SpannableString carOwnerSpannable= new SpannableString("Mayuri");
                carOwnerSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(JobDetailTabbedActivity.this,R.color.colorAccent)), 0, carOwnerName.length(), 0);
                builder.append(carOwnerSpannable);

                builder.append(" | LastName:Joshi");

                textView.settext(builder);
```

comment below if this doesn't work.

Expected Output:

Mayuri(in green color(my color accent is green)) | LastName:Joshi(In white)

add `<color name="colorAccent">#1AB394</color>`  to colors.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(name), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(name);        
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.noti_color)), 0, name.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textview.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

This code you're just using should work. I doupt the color. Test it with a simple color & fixed range:

```
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Red), 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```